# Problema para aplicação ler xlsx file no centos erro: libgcc_s.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: java, jsf, linux, centos

Estou com um grande problema e não consigo resolver tentei procurar algumas dicas na internet mais não funcionou. Por isso estou aqui e gostaria de saber se algum pode me ajudar.

Eu tenho uma aplicação web que está hospedada em uma VM CENTOS. Uma das funções dessa aplicação lê um arquivo excel que está em algum diretório dentro do centos (exemplo: `/tmp/folder/file.xlsx`).

Bom quando eu tento rodar a aplicação, ela dá o erro abaixo. Alguém saberia me dizer como resolveria essa problema?

Obrigado!

> ```
> Message: /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so: libgcc_s.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
> StackTrace: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so: libgcc_s.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
> at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
> at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:61)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
> at sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:339)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at sun.font.SunFontManager.(SunFontManager.java:335)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
> at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
> at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:490)
> at java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2059)
> ```

Comment: Sua VM é de 32 bits?

Comment: Nao a minha VM é de 64bits

Comment: Você saberia dizer se sua JVM (não sua VM) também é de 64 bits? Rodar um `java -version` no console deve mostrar isso.

Comment: o comando java -d32 funciona e o comando java -d64 nao funciona...então vejo que é a 32bits

Comment: # java -d64: Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: eu tenho ambas libraries instalada no meu centos 32bits e 64bits, mais mesmo assim não funciona

Comment: @AndréVitor este site funciona diferente de um forum, não precisa colocar RESOLVIDO no titulo, basta aceitar uma das respostas ou postar a sua propria(caso a solução encontrada seja diferente), clicando no `V` a esquerda da resposta.

Comment: Obrigado diegofm...abraços

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## O problema

Instale uma JVM de 64 bits. A sua JVM é de 32 bits, mas a sua biblioteca e a sua VM são de 64 bits, então é melhor ter a JVM também de 64 bits porque não vale a pena ter dor-de-cabeça com essas diferenças.

## Para desinstalar o Java antigo

Para desinstalar o Java, de acordo com [essa pergunta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110512), o comando a ser usado seria `sudo yum remove jdk`, e de acordo com [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756049/540552), seria `sudo yum remove java`. Se você não puder ou não quiser usar o yum para isso, então pode tentar `sudo rpm -e jdk`.

## Para instalar o Java novo

Para instalar um novo Java, de acordo com [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20901970/540552), você usaria `sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk` ou então `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`.

A outra resposta anterior indica usar (trocando-se o número da versão) `rpm -Uvh jdk-7u79-linux-x64.rpm` ou então `rpm -Uvh jdk-7u80-linux-x64.rpm`. Se preferir o Java 8, acho que o comando seria `rpm -Uvh jdk-8u102-linux-x64.rpm`.

Comment: Poderia me dizer o comando para eu retirar a JVM 32 bits e o comando para eu instalar a jvm 64bits?? nao estou encontrando na internet...obrigado

Comment: @AndréVitor Resposta editada.

Comment: Olá Victor, realmente funcionou!!!!!!Eu instalei o jdk 64 bits e deu certo agora minha aplicação roda que e´uma beleza...muito obrigado pela ajida!